# Interesting riddle game question?

Tags: game-theory

I have a row of case values with a total of 100 difference cases. I play a game with someone else and I get to go first. Each player takes turns taking a case from either end of the row. All values are known to both players and assuming the other person behaves in the most logical manner (perfect logicians), what is the best strategy for me to ensure that I end up with the majority of the money? How does it change, if at all with $n$ number of cases?

I'm thinking maybe split row in half and take from side with higher combined total? However, what if say case 1-50 sum to 1001 and case 51-100 sum to 999 but with case 100 having the value of 999? I'm also thinking that strategy may change with how many initial starting values odd vs even $n$?

Comment: It is not trivial and your idea is a poor strategy: if you start with the row $1,2,4,5,6,3$ then the first player can win by taking the $1$, and the second player should then find the $2$ and the $3$ equally attractive; if the first player initially took the $3$ then the second player could win by taking the $6$ (and later $4$ and $1$). I suspect that in general you may need to do the full $n(n-1)/2$ step analysis.

Answer (score 2):

Take the cases and number them from 1 to 100 (from one end to another). Then look how much the odd cases add up and how much the even cases add up. If the odd ones add more take number 1. After this your adversary will only be able to take even cases. This will lead to you being able to take an odd case, which again will lead the other person to only pick evens. the strategy is almost the same if the even ones add up more.

Comment: That would provide a win if there is a difference between the two sums but not if they are equal.  If they are equal, can the second player ensure a draw?

Comment: In answer to my own comment, the row $5,1,3,7,2,6,8,4$ can provide a $21-15$ win for the first player even though the odd and even positions each add up to $18$.   Take the $5$ as the initial move.

Comment: Omnitic's strategy is not quite optimal: starting with the row $4,1,3,7,2,6,8,5$ and taking $5$ initially would guarantee the first player at least $19$ (e.g. $5+6+1+7$), but I think taking $4$ initially would guarantee the first player at least $20$ (e.g. $4+8+1+7$).